# Scatter plot: How to get the name of the series into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, scatter-plot

So I would like to call the "name" in this set of data to use in a function in another part of the script.

I'm able to call the ticker, x, info, and hover variables by using

event.point.ticker, event.point.info

but I havn't figured out how to get the name of the series. I've tried multiple things such as...

series.name, this.series.name, and event.point.name, this.chart.name

all to no avail. Here is the data

```
series: 
[{
    name: 'Weak Outlook',color: 'red',data: 
    [{
        x: 40,
        y:10,
        ticker:'Michael Kors: (KORS)',
        info: 'Outlook roughly inline<br>1Q Revenue below street expectations', hover:'Guidance slightly below consensus<br>1Q Revenue to disappoint<br><a href="">read more</a>'
    },
    {
        x: 20,
        y:50,
        ticker:'Shares to sell off on earnings',
        info:'Data implies that shares, after management releases Q1 guidance, will...<br><br><a href="">read more</a>'
    },
    {
        x:0,y:0,ticker:'Zynga: (ZNGA)'
    },
    {
        x:3,y:4,ticker:'Avid: (AVID)'
    },
    {
        x:4,y:10,ticker:'JCPenny: (JCP)'
    },
    {
        x:6,y:25,ticker:'Deckers Outdoor: (DECK)'},
    {
        x:0,y:100,ticker:'Nutrisystem Corp: (NTRI)'
    },
]}],
```

and here is the function that is not working, notice that I'm passing event and series as parameters, and I'm using "series.name" to try to get the name of the series... which doesnt seem to be working

```
click: function(event,series) 
{
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/s.php?o="+event.point.ticker+"&q="+event.point.y+"&r="+event.point.x+"&s="+event.point.info+"&t="+series.name+"&u="+event.point.str5+"&v="+event.point.str6,true);
```

Comment: Which event and element (point / series) should be fired to display additional info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `event.point.series.name`  Each point holds a reference to its parent series.

- [Series API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.name)
- [Point API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.series)